# Entity framework not adding new record

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, connection-string

I have some code to add a new record to the database however, it does not appear to update the database.

```
private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
            Animal a = new Animal();
            a.AnimalName = txtNew.Text;
            db.SaveChanges();
            Debug.WriteLine(a.AnimalName);
        }
```

It is worth mentioning that I have also set one of the properties of my database to 'copy if newer' and that did not fix the problem. My connection string which was automatically generated when I created the model is as follows:

```
<add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AnimalModel.csdl|res://*/AnimalModel.ssdl|res://*/AnimalModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\dbAnimal.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

If anyone knows of a solution it would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you must write this sentence `db.animals.add(a);` before `db.SaveChanges();`

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are creating instance of Animal model but you are not adding it in db context it should be like this

```
db.Model.Add(new model)
```

and in your case it will be

```
 DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
  Animal a = new Animal();
  a.AnimalName = txtNew.Text;
  db.Animal.Add(a);
  db.SaveChanges();
  Debug.WriteLine(a.AnimalName);
```